# Authenticating with Kerberos in a disjointed namespace

Tags: dns, active-directory, kerberos

I have a problem with `Kerberos` in my network.

My Active Directory domain name is configured as `"acme.com"`. However, the `DNS suffix` is `"wifi.acme.com"`. In computer (endpoint1) I tried to execute a `SMB` query against endpoint2

```
dir \\\\endpoint2.wifi.acme.com\admin$
```

which fails with the following error:

> "The request is not supported".

I have a security policy that restricts `NTLM` outgoing connections (Network Security: Restrict `NTLM` : Outgoing `NTLM` traffic to remote servers).

In `Wireshark` I can see that the `Kerberos TGS` request returned with an error:

> "err-s-principal-unknown kerberos".

I tried the following solutions with no success:

1. Update the `msDS-AllowedDNSSuffixes` attribute with the proper `DNS suffix`.
2. Define the host name to `Kerberos realm mappings` (as in [Kerberos-SSO-Handling-Disjointed-Active-Directory-and-UNIX-DNS](https://community.centrify.com/t5/TechBlog/Kerberos-SSO-Handling-Disjointed-Active-Directory-and-UNIX-DNS/ba-p/25019))

Is there a solution to this problem without modifying the `DNS suffix` nor the `Active Directory domain` to have the same name?

Thanks.

Comment: What OS versions are computers involved (particularly endpoint1) running?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with two slashes instead of 4.

```
dir \\endpoint2.wifi.acme.com\admin$
```

The error message you get is significant.  An error 5 means you got connected, and didn't have credentials.  An error 53 means you didn't get connected.

Why are you trying **WIFI**.acme.com?  When your using an FQDN, the domain suffix usually won't make a difference (there are cases where it can).

Try just pinging the resource and see if your getting a response (or even an IP address).  I suspect your not, and that you should be going to **\endpoint2.acme.com\admin$** instead.

if all else fails, try **dir \\admin$** where IP address is the IP of the 'endpoint2' device.